# XPath of element preceding some text

Tags: html, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Trying to find the XPath for this code:

```
<a class="account-name" long-text="Sample Text" ng-
click="accountClick(account)" ng-href="sample URL" href="sample URL1">
<span>Plan Name</span></a>
```

I've tried this:

```
//span[text()='Plan Name']
```

and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: please share html code

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: For which element are you trying to get the `xpath` as per `preceding some text`? Are you refferring to **Plan Name** as text? What is your exact _Manual Step_?

Comment: What you mean by *"it doesn't seem to be working"* ? Did you get any exception? Also share your selenium code and specify programming language you use

Answer (score 1):

For this HTML,

```
<a class="account-name" long-text="Sample Text" ng-
click="accountClick(account)" ng-href="sample URL" href="sample URL1"/>
<span>Plan Name</span>
```

This XPath,

```
//span[.="Plan Name"]/preceding-sibling::a[1]
```

will selecting the immediately preceding `a` elements to `span` elements whose string value is `"Plan Name"`.

---

For this HTML,

```
<a class="account-name" long-text="Sample Text" ng-
click="accountClick(account)" ng-href="sample URL" href="sample URL1">
  <span>Plan Name</span>
</a>
```

This XPath,

```
//a[.="Plan Name"]
```

will select all `a` elements with string values equal to `"Plan Name"`.

Comment: It seem that provided source HTML is incomplete as `a` is not a self-closing tag and so I think that `span` is a child of `a` but not sibling... @Divya Karumuri can you confirm or refute this assumption?

Comment: @Andersson: Oh, well that's even easier.  I've added another XPath to cover case where the `span` is a child of the targeted `a`.  Thanks.